# JavaFX Custom Control of Label with Skin implementation

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have created a custom Led control, and because I want text within the Led and tooltip support I have thus extended Label.

If I create a LedSkin then the text is not rendered onto the custom led control. Probably because this rendering is done within the private API LabeledSkinBase which contains and adds a LabeledText and have a lot of code related to its layout.

I have been able to get text within my custom led control by adding a Label within my skin implementation, but I fear it might be missing features adherent in the Label skin implementation.

It would be so much better if it was possible to extend a public LabeledSkinBase. Instead I fear having to scavenging code from the LabeledSkinBase to use in my LedSkin.

```
public class Led extends Label {

    @Override
    protected Skin<Led> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new LedSkin(this);
    }

}

public class LedSkin extends SkinBase<Led> {

    private Label text;

    public LedSkin(Led control) {
        super(control);
        initGraphics();
    }

    private void initGraphics() {
        text = new Label();
        text.textProperty().bind(getSkinnable().textProperty());
        text.graphicProperty().bind(getSkinnable().graphicProperty());

        getChildren().setAll(text);
    }
}
```

This is actually two Label instances. One with my LedSkin and one with the default LabeledSkinBase. It seems kinda like an overkill, but I cannot use the LabeledText because that one is internal private class.

Is there not a better way?

Comment: [`LabeledSkinBase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/LabeledSkinBase.html) is public API in Java 9 and later.

Comment: We are stuck with Java 8 for the time being. What should I have as minimum in my LedSkin until I can extends LabeledSkinBase?